# Can you ping someone who has hammer closed?

Tags: discussion

For example, if you think someone has hammer dupe closed for the wrong reason, can you ping(@..) them in the comments?

I don't have a specific example, I just couldn't find the answer.

Comment: Yes, you can ping duplicate hammers but you have to type their username yourself, it won't auto-complete

Comment: Thanks @rene, do you know this from experience, or is there some page on all things communication-related out there that I've missed?

Comment: Here is the link to the SE wide FAQ on the complete topic: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Comment: That’s perfect, thanks!